# How to place text through parameters in a video at different position

Tags: video, text, runtime

I am asked to create a video where texts are inserted dynamically at
various points in the video. Its kinda like creating personalized 
video. For example a person's name is given as a parameter to the swf file,
then that name is inserted inside the video at runtime.

I am new to video editing and it will be of great help if anyone could guide
me which product i should be looking on.

With adobe cs4 professional, I tried creating cue points but the issue is i
can't place the text at the coordinates where  i want to in the video.

After that, i tried with adobe after effects, now i am able to create text
layer and place the text whereever i want to. But i am at loss to figure
out how to pass the value for the text layer dynamically.

It will be of great help if anyone can give me some idea of how to do  it.

Thanks

Ragu

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty special use for text in a video, so I doubt that you will find a tool which supports that out of the box. You best bet is using a video editing framework or change the source code for the flash video player (for example, [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/)) to accept texts with coordinates from a second URL and display that.